# What's wrong with adding Admob to my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I want to add Admob, but I have the following problem with my layout:

[image]

I want it to appear at the bottom of the screen instead.

This is my `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/reklam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contextClickable="false">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the desired result?

Comment: I added picture. adding middle of screen. I want to bottom of screen

Answer (score 0):

You want to add your AdView in the FrameLayout at runtime. Try this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then in your activity onCreate:

```
mAdView = new AdView(this);
myAdView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                     FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                     FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                     Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM));
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
layout.addView(mAdView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111")
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: sorry but I didnt. Im newbie. I change my activity_main.xml with ur code. Than I add on create but I have some errros. http://prntscr.com/8uytfh set gravity not resolve and how I change setLayoutParams

Comment: You need to import the right classes com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize andcom.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.  I have updated the setGravity and LayoutParams since setGravity does not exist anymore.

Comment: My imports import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

Comment: Made a small adjustment... you should be using `AdRequest.Builder` to get your AdRequest object. Have a look at this link https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: thanks for everything. This solved adrequest problem. But http://prntscr.com/8uyz8d this problem contunie

Comment: Made another adjustment in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

try to put these parameters in your Admob xml :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Comment: you must have a relativeLayout as XML root !!

Comment: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  I got this error If I change to relativelayout

Comment: no just put android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  under RelativeLayout ;)